# How a copy statement recognizes its constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

In the following code when the statement `X loc2 = loc;` is executed the compiler recognizes that the constructor below should run, and then runs it.
`X(const X& x) { val = x.val; out("X(X&)"); }`

I know that constructor is said to be a *copy constructor* but my question is that how the compiler knows that constructor is of that statement? Is there any rule about how should the structure of a *copy constructor* be so that it can be recognized and ran when a copy statement is executed?

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"
using namespace std;

struct X {
    int val;
    void out(const string& s) 
           {cerr << this << " -> " << s << ": " << val << "\n\n"; }


    X(int v) { val = v; out("X(int)"); }

    X(const X& x) { val = x.val; out("X(X&)"); } // The copy constructor

};

int main()
{  
    X loc(4);
    X loc2 = loc; // This statement

    char ch;
    cin>>ch;
    return 0;
}
```

std_lib_facilities is [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). 
The OS I use is Windows and my compiler is Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as a constructor has one of the following forms, it will be adopted automatically on compilation as the *copy constructor*:

```
X(const X& );
X(X&);
X(volatile X& );
X(const volatile X& );
X(const X&, /*any number of arguments with default values*/);
X(X&, /*any number of arguments with default values*/);
```

Adopt the first one unless you have a good reason to adopt an alternative.